# Sinon - spy on instanceof

Tags: node.js, sinon, instanceof, spy

How can I spy on instanceof? I tried doing:

```
let spy = sinon.spy(global, 'instanceof')
```

but that doesn't work, I'm trying to test it to make sure it was called;

Comment: instanceof is an operator, not a method. It didn't make a lot of sense, though, you should be checking a result of using it, not that it was called.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if you *really* want to do this, you can write a simple wrapper around `instanceof`:

```
utils.isInstanceOf = function(obj, cls) {
    return obj instanceof cls;
};


let spy = sinon.spy(utils, 'isInstanceOf')
```

Then you can invoke `utils.isInstanceOf` in your code instead of using `instanceof` directly.